# Spark scala - Dataframes comparison

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

How to compare 2 Dataframes based on PK.

Basically want to create a scala spark code to compare 2 big Dataframes (10M records each, 100 columns each) and show output as:

```
ID   Diff
1 [ {Col1: [1,2]}, {col3: [5,10]} ...]
2 [ {Col3: [4,2]}, {col7: [2,6]} ...]
```

ID is PK

Diff column - show first Column name where is the difference and then which value is different one from another in that column.

Comment: It's not a simple problem, but surprisingly doable.  Here's just a rough bit of what I started with: `val text = ds1.columns.filter(_ != "id").map(c => when(ds1(c) =!= ds2(c), concat_ws("", lit(s"{$c: ["), ds1(c), lit(","), ds2(c), lit("]}"))) as c)`.  It would take a good amount of time to put it all together though.

Comment: Test output for that looked like: `{value: [foo,bar]}`

Answer (score 3):

Each different column can be converted to string, and then all columns are concated:

```
// ---- data ---
val leftDF = Seq(
  (1, 1, 5, 0),
  (2, 0, 4, 2)
).toDF("ID", "Col1", "col3", "col7")
val rightDF = Seq(
  (1, 2, 10, 0),
  (2, 0, 2, 6)
).toDF("ID", "Col1", "col3", "col7")

def getDifferenceForColumn(name: String): Column =
  when(
    col("l." + name) =!= col("r." + name),
    concat(lit("{" + name + ": ["), col("l." + name), lit(","), col("r." + name), lit("]}")))
    .otherwise(lit(""))

val diffColumn = leftDF
  .columns
  .filter(_ != "ID")
  .map(name => getDifferenceForColumn(name))
  .reduce((l, r) => concat(l,
    when(length(r) =!= 0 && length(l) =!= 0, lit(",")).otherwise(lit(""))
    , r))


val diffColumnWithBraces = concat(lit("["), diffColumn, lit("]"))

leftDF
  .alias("l")
  .join(rightDF.alias("r"), Seq("id"))
  .select(col("ID"), diffColumnWithBraces.alias("DIFF"))
```

Output:

```
+---+------------------------------+
|ID |DIFF                          |
+---+------------------------------+
|1  |[{Col1: [1,2]},{col3: [5,10]}]|
|2  |[{col3: [4,2]},{col7: [2,6]}] |
+---+------------------------------+
```

If columns cannot have value "}{", in solution above two variables can be changed, maybe, performance can be better:

```
 val diffColumns = leftDF
      .columns
      .filter(_ != "ID")
      .map(name => getDifferenceForColumn(name))

val diffColumnWithBraces = concat(lit("["), regexp_replace(concat(diffColumns: _*),"\\}\\{","},{"), lit("]"))
```

Comment: When having big data - getting memory overhead exception.. is there a way to limit memory usage (make it with less memory usage)?

Comment: Similar approach, which can consume less memory added at the end; also answer with UTF can be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Also UDF can be used, incoming data and output is the same as in my first answer:

```
val colNames = leftDF
  .columns
  .filter(_ != "ID")

val generateSeqDiff = (colNames: Seq[String], leftValues: Seq[Any], rightValues: Seq[Any]) => {
  val nameValues = colNames
    .zip(leftValues)
    .zip(rightValues)
    .filterNot({ case ((_, l), r) => l == r })
    .map({ case ((name, l), r) => s"{$name: [$l,$r]}" })
    .mkString(",")
  s"[$nameValues]"
}
val generateSeqDiffUDF = udf(generateSeqDiff)

leftDF
  .select($"ID", array(colNames.head, colNames.tail: _*).alias("leftValues"))
  .alias("l")
  .join(
    rightDF
      .select($"ID", array(colNames.head, colNames.tail: _*).alias("rightValues"))
      .alias("r"), Seq("id"))
  .select($"ID", generateSeqDiffUDF(lit(colNames), $"leftValues", $"rightValues").alias("DIFF"))
```